# Incremental backup using snapshot in Amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am having issue in creating the incremental backup using snapshot.

Last week i took the backup of the drive which is 30Gb of size using the snapshot,and yesterday i have added 5 more Gb of data to the same drive and took another backup as a second snapshot.

Today when i am restoring the data using the second snapshot, I could see that there was around 35 GB of data rather than the incremental backup of 5GB

Can someone please tell me reason behind this

Answer (score 3):

When you restore an EBS snapshot, you are restoring a block based image of your volume. This overwrites the EBS volume.

Restoring a snapshot does not perform a file based restore. The restore is all or nothing. This is the reason that 35 GB was restored instead of 5 GB.

The incremental nature of snapshots allows for point in time restores and for space savings (the space to store the snapshot).

This article will help explain EBS snapshots:

[EBS Snapshots Explained](https://blog.skeddly.com/2017/03/ebs-snapshots-explained.html)